# How can I wait for all the hooks to finish loading before rendering the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that has many hooks, for example:

```
import useProfilePermission from 'hooks/useProfilePermission'



  const { a } = useProfilePermission(1)
  const { b } = useProfilePermission(2)
  const { c } = useProfilePermission(3)
  const { d } = useProfilePermission(4)
```

Later I use these variables a, b, c, d and do some conditional rendering

The useProfilePermission makes a network request so It takes some time to load, How do I wait for variables to completely load before the get to the **return** statement for that functional component?

Comment: add an "isLoading" state in the hook (and return it). Initialize it to true and set it to false when the function terminates. Then use this state to wait for completion in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the permissions (a, b, c, d) are `undefined` or `null` until the api ends, you can return `null` (or a spinner) from the component:

```
const { a } = useProfilePermission(1)
const { b } = useProfilePermission(2)
const { c } = useProfilePermission(3)
const { d } = useProfilePermission(4)

if(!a || !b || !c || !d) return null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return state(isLoading) from useProfilePermission() and use it.

const {a , isLoading} = useProfilePermission(1)

if(isLoading) showLoading()...

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering here.
The condition would be that all of the constants resulting from the request are not null or not undefined (e.g.you could cast to a boolean by using the double exclamation mark), or that they are equal to a certain string (e.g. a.status === 'ok').

```
const App = () => {
  const a = usePermission(1_000)
  const b = usePermission(2_000)
  const c = usePermission(3_000)

  return (
    !!a && !!b && !!c 
        ? <p>got permission</p>
        : <p>loading....</p> // or null
    
  )
}

/* or like this : */

const App = () => {
  const a = usePermission(1_000)
  const b = usePermission(2_000)
  const c = usePermission(3_000)

  return (
    a.status === 'ok' && b.status === 'ok' && c.status === 'ok' 
        ? <p>got permission</p>
        : <p>loading....</p> // or null
    
  )
}
```

Here a working simplified version : [link](https://reactplayground.vercel.app/#N4IglgdgJgpgHgOgFYGcQC5wFsAOB7AJwBcACAQRxxIDMC8sSByBAegp2RTkYB0IxchUgCUYAQwDGpWvSYFxU3v0HESwEhPliiMYXjykAvjToNGWqQFoo9FhIA2YGBCJK+EvBBSkPLsZBgCEgBeEhsJAFcsZyIEAHMYIgBRexholwAhAE8ASSgACnN9VwBKd09vEjoDEI0tHT0DfN8ifwhAsohq2PloQPy+EhJRSVjNcR0UtJiBiCGhkakEAGUiAjApAFk8WAAaQfmICPt7fbn5xbH6mCn0onz2TqHOkpBdkHZOOAxsfFVL3ZqEgRFAwVbaGAkYwyMwWVx8AR-UjqEEwAAKgSwYBQKDAnihJlkzBYqIxBCxOLxEDcEF8lXYtXyJRCAD41AcWCwSEQABaQnn6ADWJFGETEJyyJE89kl8iIEQIXm5BAikLE1B0QTEGkCrUgIqweAiLil1G5AhggKIeBIuKwxwhIpICVI8gAjqrvAc6aRtaFSZjsbjPPkAIwAfQADNGnhoKqQAEa1APkoNU-IAJijMe98Y0ydBZIpwYg+QAzNnI50DnKFXNZvMSABCJvagBkbebTaTHa7EhInJIYFIAHcwCduWJBZCy7aYL4oChuTb5Cg8PYAG4wA6NgD8JAAPDgWXEajhA5TPAeWMed-N0Ifj-Y8GIoJA4ghPwhr8eB1zCCQRwnHeBydIYfB8PASJhDA1BiMcpDsG8IApsWVJfD8iJCMMChEICKKgkk1DUPOeHAqCojUICqLgjoBIwnIuE0lB2E+uR6IXiWtRYEuwRssAuZeKQADaq6AqCRCiCgAC6BZgq0Oj5HB9igtW5yokRJFSPkTKsuy5xDGxYBQLUEkACoWka9y6XxQwCQZ8wSVJ+RrKqsZDIYgI8Wpja1oqJA2WyDjiAQFnRFZ+TGbGnkkMJ0k+VUiR1olKB8IYICGEAA)

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `useEffect` and `useState`.

```js
...
function App(){
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const { a } = useProfilePermission(1);
    const { b } = useProfilePermission(2);
    const { c } = useProfilePermission(3);
    const { d } = useProfilePermission(4);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (a && b && c && d) setIsLoading(false)
    }, [a, b, c, d]);
    if (isLoading) return null; // skip the render
    return <view>...</view>
}
```